# Chrome -webkit-clip-path and outline bug

Tags: css, google-chrome, clip

I've found rather strange behaviour in Chrome's (30.0.1599.69) `-webkit-clip-path` and want to know if it's a bug or not.

When element has clip-path set to rectangle, and then something on the page gets ouline (for example, due to focus), clip-path shifts vertically. After outline is removed, clip-path doesn't take previous position.

[A page to reproduce it](http://jsbin.com/UPIQatO/3).

Intial state:

[image: everything's okay]

Something gets an outline:

[image: bug is clearly visible]

And then without outline:

[image]

Note: since further outline changes don't affect the clipping, it can be used for our advantage to "fix" the issue by applying an outline of known height and then offseting clip-path for this value.

#### Update:

[An issue in Chromium bugtracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=363097).

I've found out that `rectangle()` support [was removed](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=125235), but not sure from what versions (does iOS still have it?). `polygon()` version [works fine here in Canary (at April 17, 2014)](http://jsbin.com/xujitaje/7/edit).

Comment: make sure to look in the chromium project to see if maybe there is a bug.. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: Thanks, I've looked through suspicious "clip-path" and "outline" issues, but found nothing similar.

Comment: what exactly is your end result?

Comment: That looks like a genuine bug. Have you filed a report?

Answer (score 1):

That does look like a bug in Chrome. I'm not sure if you're just asking if this looks like a bug or if it's actually a nuisance for you in a project you're working on. In case of the latter, you can get around the bug you've found by removing the standard Chrome outline on focus, and optionally replacing it with a box shadow if you'd like it to look the same. For example:

```
input:focus {
    outline: none;

    // Optionally do something like this
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px blue;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px blue;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this bug or similar in chrome too. relating to -webkit-clip-path. I've looked and there doesn't seem to be an issue raised (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list). Your test no longer seems to work as you described.